# VB6 and C# regexes

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, vb6, vb6-migration

I need to convert a VB6(which I'm not fammiliar with) project to C# 4.0 one. The project contains some regexes for string validation.

I need to know if the regexes behave the same in both cases, so if i just copy the regex string from the VB6 project, to the C# project, will they work the same?

I have a basic knowledge of regexes and I can just about read what one does, but for flavors and such, that's a bit over my head at the moment.

For example, are these 2 lines equivalent?

VB6:

```
isStringValid = (str Like "*[!0-9A-Z]*")
```

C#:

```
isStringValid = Regex.IsMatch(str, "*[!0-9A-Z]*");
```

Thanks!

Comment: It entirely depends on the regex. If it is simple it should just copy fine, if it is complex, it might not.

Comment: Chances are high that they will work, but there are many subtle differences, so you should post some examples. If you need to bulk convert them, consider investing in [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com).

Comment: well, it is more of a general question: will regexes work the same or not? if it depends on the regex, then the answer would be: no :) But i'll post the one regex that prompted me to ask this question.

Comment: i think the regex strings should work just fine. both VB and C# are .NET languages and use the same regex "flavor"

Comment: @toadzky: VB6 was the version before VB adopted the .NET framework with Visual Basic .NET. The differences between VB6 and VB.NET are so large, they should be considered different languages, not versions of the same language.

Comment: sorry about that. i've never done vb, i prefer c#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The old VB `Like` operator, despite appearances, is not a regular expression interface. It's more of a glob pattern matcher. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

In your example:

```
Like "*[!0-9A-Z]*"
```

Matches strings that start and end with any character (zero or more), then *doesn't* match an alphanumeric character somewhere in the middle. The regular expression for this would be:

```
/.*[^0-9A-Z].*/
```

---

**EDIT** To answer your question: No, the two can't be used interchangeably. However, it's fairly easy to convert `Like`'s operand into a proper regular expression:

```
Like       RegEx
========== ==========
?          .
*          .*
#          \d
[abc0-9]   [abc0-9]
[!abc0-9]  [^abc0-9]
```

There are a few caveats to this, but that should get you started and cover most cases.

Comment: Thank you, this explains exactly what I was trying to find out.

Answer (score -1):

In a word, yes.

These are the same. Some quick googling should give you answers to more complex issues.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/bce145b8-95d4-4be4-8b07-e8adee7286f1/

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Comment: The VB6 `Like` operator doesn't use regular expressions.