# vb6 Like vs vb.net regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to convert one vb6.0 project into vb.Net project. I am not much familiar with .Net regular expressions. What will be the regular expression in vb.net that will be equivalent to vb Like `"*_?#"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB6 and C# regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820896/vb6-and-c-sharp-regexes)

Comment: What's the problem to continue [using `Like` in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB6 'Like' [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx):

```
* = zero or more characters
_ = _ character
? = any single character
# = any digit (0-9)
```

[.NET Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#quantifiers) equivalent:

```
.* = zero or more characters 
_ = _ character
. = any single character
\d = any single digit
```

So your regex string is '.*_.\d'

**Edit**: replaced `[0-9]` with `\d`

Comment: Simple consise answer that provides syntax, hyperlinks and is nicely formatted too. Have a cookie.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Juffy for help. Just added {1}$ at the end of expression. That means my final expression is  :-                     '.*_.[0-9]{1}$'  and it worked for me.

Comment: I don't really know .net regex flavor but the `{1}` is probably useless.

Comment: Yeah, I think the `{1}` is redundant. The `\d` should only match one character.